# Initialize Struct from array keys

Tags: arrays, ruby, struct

I have

```
arrs = [[:key1, key2, key3, key4],[:key6, key7]]
```

And I want to define `Struct` by using those keys like this:

```
arrs.map do |arr|
  Struct.new(arr)
end
```

but it does raise an error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String
    from (irb):26:in `new'
    from (irb):26
```

So, do we have any way to initialize these keys in `Struct`?

Comment: MAybe this will helps https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want the result of your code to be? What does `test` have to do with it? Why are you assigning to `test` and then never ever using the result?

Comment: oop my bad, i'll remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the splat operator:

```
arrs = [[:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4],[:key6, :key7]]
arrs.map { |a| Struct.new(*a) }
=> [#<Class:0x007fa833e25738>, #<Class:0x007fa833e1fa18>]
```